# Does $f^{-1}(B^\circ)\subset (f^{-1}(B))^\circ$ imply continuity?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity

Let $(X,\tau),(Y,\eta)$ be topological spaces and  $f:X\to Y$ a function. Prove that  $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(B^\circ)\subset (f^{-1}(B))^\circ,\forall B\subset Y$

$\implies$

Let $B\subset Y.$ As $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(B^\circ)=(f^{-1}(B^\circ))^\circ\subset (f^{-1}(B))^\circ$

$\Longleftarrow$

What can I do to prove this side?

Is the implication $\implies$ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first implication is already too terse, I think. 
Suppose that $f$ is continuous. Let $B \subseteq Y$.

Then $B^\circ$ is open and $B^\circ \subseteq B$. So $f^{-1}[B^\circ]$ is open as $f$ is continuous. Also $f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$. So as $(f^{-1}[B])^\circ$ is the union of all open subsets of $f^{-1}[B]$ (the definition of interior) we thus have $f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq (f^{-1}[B])^\circ$, as required.

A more "axiomatic" way (using the axioms for an interior operator) would be :

$$f^{-1}[B^\circ] = f^{-1}[B^\circ]^\circ \subseteq f^{-1}[B]^\circ$$
where the first equality just says that $f^{-1}[B^\circ]$ is open and the inclusion follows as interiors respect inclusions).

This shows $\Rightarrow$.

For $\Leftarrow$: Suppose that for all $B \subseteq Y$, we have $f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]^\circ$.

We want to show $f$ is continuous so take $O$ to be an arbitrary open subset of $Y$, and we need to show $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$.

Then $O^\circ = O$ and so

$$f^{-1}[O]^\circ \subseteq f^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[O^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[O]^\circ \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$$

where the first and last inclusions follow from $A^\circ \subseteq A$ for all $A$, we then use $O =O^\circ$ and then the identity on the right hand side in our assumption, for $B=O$. All inclusions together show $f^{-1}[O]^\circ  =f^{-1}[O]$ so $f^{-1}[O]$ is open.

Comment: Thanks Henno, just one thing I think the last term it's not necessary, just the first 4 terms are enough to conclude that $f$ is continuos.

Comment: @Isabella True. I wasn't striving for minimality.

Answer (score 3):

For an open set $G$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(G)=f^{-1}(G^{\circ})\subseteq(f^{-1}(G))^{\circ}\subseteq f^{-1}(G)$, so $f^{-1}(G)=(f^{-1}(G))^{\circ}$.

Comment: So $f$ is continuous. This $\implies$ side is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, it looks good.